# BeautifulSoup always returns null when I use findAll

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to use BeautifulSoup to parse some webpages, and it always returns null whenever I use findAll even though I can access stuff like soup.title and whatnot just fine.

I'm trying to use [this link](http://www.newegg.com/Product/ProductList.aspx?Submit=ENE&IsNodeId=1&Description=nvidia%20gtx%20560%20ti&bop=And&Order=PRICE&PageSize=20) to parse right now, and this is what I get when I try doing stuff with it:

```
>>> site = urllib2.urlopen('http://www.newegg.com/Product/ProductList.aspx?Submit=ENE&IsNodeId=1&Description=nvidia%20gtx%20560%20ti&bop=And&Order=PRICE&PageSize=20')                                                                                                                            
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(site)                                                                                  
>>> soup.title                                                                                                                                   
<title>Newegg.com - nvidia gtx 560 ti</title>                                                                                                    
>>> soup.findAll('title')                                                                                                                        
Null                                                                                                                                             
>>>
```

Does anyone know why it's doing this? I'm using BeautifulSoup 2.1.1

Comment: If you still can, jump to scrapy. It's more powerful and is still supported

Comment: Your url link gives me malformed start tag error. I tried the code on the other websites, everything is just fine.

Comment: Works for me with BeautifulSoup 3.2.0 and the URL from the example.

Answer (score 1):

You are using an old version of BeautifulSoup that doesn't have the `findAll` method. I believe the equivalent method for old versions was called `fetch`. The `findAll` method was added in BeautifulSoup version 3.0.0, when the method names were changed to be more consistent. From the documentation:

> Previous versions of Beautiful Soup had methods like first, fetch, and fetchPrevious. These methods are sitll there, but they're deprecated, and may go away soon. The total effect of all those names was very confusing. The new names are named consistently: as mentioned above, if the method name is plural or refers to All, it returns multiple objects. Otherwise, it returns one object.